# How to cross tabulate the summary values across same field

Tags: r, dplyr

This may have solutions/answers available here, but I am unable to find.

Let us assume a simple data like this

```
x <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, each = 2),
                v1 = c('A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C'))

> x
  id v1
1  1  A
2  1  B
3  2  A
4  2  B
5  3  A
6  3  C
```

Now I want an **output** of relation of `V1` column with itself, but across group on `id` something like this

```
  v1        A     B     C
1 A         0     2     1
2 B         2     0     0
3 C         1     0     0
```

So, I proceeded like this..

```
library(tidyverse)

#merged the V1 column by itself with all = TRUE
x <- merge(x, x, by = "id", all = T)

# removed same group rows
x <- x[x$v1.x != x$v1.y, ]

# final code
x %>% select(-id) %>%
  group_by(v1.x, v1.y) %>%
  summarise(val = n()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = v1.y, values_from = val, values_fill = 0L, names.sort = T)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   v1.x [3]
  v1.x      A     B     C
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 A         0     2     1
2 B         2     0     0
3 C         1     0     0
```

My question is that any better/direct method to obtain the cross-table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a contingency table with `xtabs` (which can work with large data sets as well). Then, you can use `crossprod` on the table and set the diagonal to zero for the final result.

```
ct <- xtabs(~ id + v1, data = x)
cp <- crossprod(ct, ct)
diag(cp) <- 0
cp
```

Instead of `xtabs` you can create a cross-table with simply `table` as well. As noted by @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1, you can simplify to a nice one-liner equivalent:

```
"diag<-"(crossprod(table(x)), 0)
```

**Output**

```
   v1
v1  A B C
  A 0 2 1
  B 2 0 0
  C 1 0 0
```